# How can i change this to String in java

Tags: java, android, string, nullpointerexception, byte

in my program, i have `capkTable` `Java` class which is a `String`. In another class, i want to get a data, so i can use `appState.capkTable.setCapki(data[i+3])`.
knowing fully well that `(data[i+3])` is a byte.

How can i convert it to `String`?

what i did is this :

```
byte[] testing = new byte [(data[i+3])];
int tagDataLength = 0;
appState.capkTable.setCapki(StringUtil.toString(AppUtil.removeTailF(ByteUtil.bcdToAscii(testing,  0, tagDataLength))));
```

i don't know if i am doing it the right way..cos, instead of getting a value, it's returning `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: appState.capkTable.setCapki(String.valueOf(data[i+3]));

Comment: Thanks so much....kind of easy

Answer (score 0):

Try replacnig this

```
StringUtil.toString(AppUtil.removeTailF(ByteUtil.bcdToAscii(testing,  0, tagDataLength))));
```

With this:

```
String.valueOf(AppUtil.removeTailF(ByteUtil.bcdToAscii(testing,  0, tagDataLength))));
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two...please.

Comment: `StringUtil.toString` and `String.valueOf`